# what is the fault with c here?

Tags: c, function

Please excuse me for asking this, because I know the code I'm gonna give you is wrong. Being a newbie I am not able to find the fault. Please help me correct the question and give a solution as well. Again I'm sorry to bother with this simple problem. Tomorrow is my exm in C so i'm kinda desperate. :(

Q: What will be the output of the program?

First let me show you how I find the code first:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

    int funct l(int n){
    if (n>3)
        return int funct(n-3)));

    }

    main() {
    int n= 10;
    printf("%d", funct l (n));

    }
```

Then I thought i'd correct it. Then I cleaned up the code as far as i can. Then the code came to this:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int funct(int n){
    if (n>3){
        return funct(n-3);
    }
}

main() {
    int n= 10;
    printf("%d", funct(n));



}
```

still it doesn't give proper answer (though I don't know what it'll show). It is either 1 or 2 and process returned 1 (0*1) is showing at the last line.

Please help me out!

Comment: `func` doesn't return. Stop doing what you're doing and learn how to use your compiler: *any* compiler that's run properly will give you a loud and clear warning about this kind of obvious error. You don't need Stack Overflow. You just need to listen to your compiler.

Comment: I would recommend turning up the warning level on your compiler to maximum. Most compilers can automatically warn you when a function doesn't return a value, which would help you spot the error here.

Comment: Hint: what should `funct` return if `n` <= 3?

Comment: The fault with C is probably between chair and keyboard...

Answer (score 1):

Your `funct` function doesn't always return a value. This means that it could return anything. Try this:

```
int funct(int n) {
    if (n > 3)
        return funct(n - 3);
    return n;
}
```

Here is the call stack when n = 10

```
funct(n = 10)
    funct(n = 7)
        funct(n = 4)
            funct(n = 1)
                return 1
            return 1
        return 1
    return 1
```

Here is the call stack when n = 11

```
funct(n = 11)
    funct(n = 8)
        funct(n = 5)
            funct(n = 2)
                return 2
            return 2
        return 2
    return 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. but in this code: 
`
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n>1)
     return n*factorial(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter an positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Factorial of %d = %ld", n, factorial(n));
    return 0;
}`
at the deceleration of the function the return type is the function. what am i missing here?

Comment: @user3663862 That is a different question than that under discussion here and unlikely to be answered. Accept cabellicar123's answer if it solves the question you have asked. Ask your second question as a new distinct question and if it relates to this, reference it with a link.

Comment: By doing what @cabellicat123 told me to do:

#include<stdio.h>

int funct(int n){
    if (n<3){
        return funct(n-3);
        return n;
    }
}

main() {
    int n= 10;
    printf("%d", funct(n));
    return 0;
}

out put is 10. Is that the answer what the program supposed to give?

Comment: @user3663862 sorry typo. Fixed.

Comment: Its output is again 1 or 2 if I change the value of n. :( 
@cabellicar123

Comment: @user3663862 It is supposed to depend on n. Check the edit.